# Can't run "System.Windows.Forms application" while testing a Hello World code after fresh installation

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm a linux (Slackware 14.2) user and needed to install **mono** for a work project on my computer. After installing the slackbuild I ran the code from https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/ which worked great until I tried to use '**System.Windows.Forms**' as follow:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class HelloWorld : Form
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Application.Run (new HelloWorld ());
    }

    public HelloWorld ()
    {
        Text = "Hello Mono World";
    }
}
```

After compiling and running I get:

```
$ mono hello.exe 

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Drawing.KnownColors' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Drawing.GDIPlus' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: libgdiplus.so.0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x000ab] in <ac0a7ab7ad9c4534aa7b9d68ccc688c1>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.KnownColors..cctor () [0x0001a] in <ac0a7ab7ad9c4534aa7b9d68ccc688c1>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Color.get_Black () [0x00000] in <ac0a7ab7ad9c4534aa7b9d68ccc688c1>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic..cctor () [0x00000] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine..cctor () [0x0002f] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () [0x00000] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x000e4] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor () [0x00000] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00014] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () [0x0000e] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00012] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at HelloWorld..ctor () [0x00000] in <ebd84f70eef34e1bac9228a36ebc3550>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) HelloWorld:.ctor ()
  at HelloWorld.Main () [0x00001] in <ebd84f70eef34e1bac9228a36ebc3550>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Drawing.KnownColors' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Drawing.GDIPlus' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: libgdiplus.so.0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x000ab] in <ac0a7ab7ad9c4534aa7b9d68ccc688c1>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.KnownColors..cctor () [0x0001a] in <ac0a7ab7ad9c4534aa7b9d68ccc688c1>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Color.get_Black () [0x00000] in <ac0a7ab7ad9c4534aa7b9d68ccc688c1>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic..cctor () [0x00000] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine..cctor () [0x0002f] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () [0x00000] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x000e4] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor () [0x00000] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00014] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () [0x0000e] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00012] in <cfc91f7a5a0243dda6f0da9f9f2bd749>:0 
  at HelloWorld..ctor () [0x00000] in <ebd84f70eef34e1bac9228a36ebc3550>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) HelloWorld:.ctor ()
  at HelloWorld.Main () [0x00001] in <ebd84f70eef34e1bac9228a36ebc3550>:0
```

Is there anything I did wrong (or didn't do)?

Comment: `---> System.DllNotFoundException: libgdiplus.so.0` Looks like you are missing at least one shared library on your system.

Comment: Nope, also checked that before. It's in /usr/lib EDIT: should it be somewhere else? I'm confused now.

Comment: Well, your system tells you it either (a) can't find it or (b) can't load it. In case of (b) a `ldd /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so.0` might be enlightening. F.ex. `/usr/lib/` probably indicates a 32-bit library and that one won't work for a 64-bit executable.

Comment: Yeah. I had the x86 lib installed and let this pass unnoticed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't notice I had a 32-bit lib installed. Perfectly working now.
Thanks [Stefan Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8866606/stefan-becker).